# How to set example for Vector[SomeTrait] in swagger model

Tags: scala, rest, annotations, swagger

The api request looks like -

```
case class SomeRequest(@ApiModelProperty(example = "FirstOption") options: Vector[Option])

sealed trait Option {
  def name: String
}

object Option {

  case object FirstOption extends Option {
    override val name: String = "FirstOption"
  }

}
```

When example is not set for the parameter, the model is like -

```
{
  "options" : [
     "string"
  ]
}
```

and when value is set in example then

```
{
  "options" : "FirstOption"
}
```

whereas it should be

```
   {
      "options" : [
         "FirstOption"
      ]
    }
```

Have same issue when setting example for Seq[String].

These are the project dependencies.

[image: swagger dependencies]
How can we create the model properly ?

Answer (score 0):

Changed to look into a yaml file for model, than setting annotations. Worked perfectly!